# minizinc syntax to specify random distribution for value selection

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

Does minizinc have any syntax to specify the distribution of values selection of a variable. For eg.

```
var 0..100: X ;
```

I would like to specify that X take values in range 0..50 90% of the time and take values in 51..100 10% of time. The syntax

```
int_search( [X], first_fail, **indomain_random**, complete ) satisfy;
```

specifies that X may get any value in 0..100 with the same probability.

Answer (score 1):

MiniZinc don't have any syntax to state such a random distribution.

One way might be to change the FlatZinc solver so it behave this way when "indomain_random" is used. Though this requires that you have access to the source of the FlatZinc solver.

That said, what exactly is your use case for wanting this distribution?

Comment: i'm looking to generate multiple solutions based on a set of constraints and would like to use the solutions as inputs to a testing framework. And since some inputs are more likely, i'd like the random distribution for variables to be skewed towards the more-likely scenario.

Comment: What I would do in such a case is to generate the model by another program setting X to a fixed parameter (with a value generated from this distribution).

An another way is to run the "minizinc" (or "mzn2fzn") with the command line option "-D" to define X as a parameter to the model. Example: 'minizinc -D "X=3" model.mzn' (X is now fixed to the value 3).